# Cannot update Windows if it is not in the beginning of the disk

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, ssd, windows-update

I've been having this issue since ages, so I decided to give it a go here. I've looked around but have found no valid solutions. Please point me to a duplicate should you find one.

### The problem:

My Windows 10 cannot get updated. It suggest an update, downloads it, tells me that I need to reboot, reboots the system, loads the old state and shows a message, that an error was encountered during the update and the system was reverted to the old state. If I go to the update menu after that it suggests [fixing the issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEa9x.png) and fails to do it with the message "Cannot update System Partition". After searching what can be the cause for quite some time, I have narrowed down the issue to the fact that Windows is not installed in the beginning of the disk. See the details about my system below.

### Details:

- Dual Boot with Ubuntu 16.04.
- Two SSDs, one for both systems, one for data.
- The disk partitioning looks like this: [Disk Partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3246j.png) (sorry, cannot include inline, new to this part of Stack Exchange)

### Questions:

- Did anyone encounter this issue?
- How can I get a better error message?
- Can I move Windows to the beginning of space?

Comment: I don't think location is the problem, but perhaps the fact that you deleted the System Reserved partition. I don't remember if it's labeled that way in the UEFI/GPT installation but I'm certain a typical installation of Windows these days always produce at least two NTFS partition (unless there is an existing Windows installation which has two already). And quite obviously you deleted the smaller one (IIRC ~450M).

Comment: Thanks a lot @TomYan. That might be the case. I will look into that.